# the constant of the Cox model

Tags: r, cox-regression

I have computed a prognostic model using the Cox model (`coxph` function in R). I provide the standardised regression coefficients in my paper.

However, a reviewer ask me to give the constant of the Cox model.

Is it the same than the baseline function?
How to report such value in my paper?

Thank for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Cox’ proportional hazard model

[image]

the baseline hazard h0 is the value of the hazard where all predictor variables are equal to zero.

Let’s take as sample data the `lung` data from `survival`:

We fit the model with

```
m <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
```

Then the logarithm of the baseline hazard is given by

```
predict(m, data.frame(sex = 0))
#[1] 0.7406381
```